# Carrying a large amount of cash out of the US during a flight with a connection

Tags: international-travel, money

Say I want to take 15,000 US dollars out of the US. The destination is country "B" (say somewhere in middle-east), but I also have a connection in country "A" (say somewhere in Europe).
I am aware that I need to comply with the rules in the US (FinCEN 105) and with the destination country "B" (whatever rule it is). But what about the rules in country "A"; do I have investigate the travel rules in country "A" (the connection country) to see if I have to fulfill any requirements?

Comment: Will you remain airside in country “A” or will you need to clear Customs & Immigration?

Comment: @Traveller thanks. I am not going to go inside country "A". It is only a connecting flight (it is a few hours of stay in the airport of country "A"). So, I guess I remain airside in country "A". Here I am assuming that using a country as only a connection does not require me to clear Customs & Immigration (However I am not sure if that is true for all the countries? please inform).

Comment: Please see [this](https://www.politico.eu/article/ecj-travelers-must-declare-cash-even-in-transit-areas-of-airports/) from 2017. *"Passengers carrying €10,000 or more in cash have to declare the money to customs officials even if they remain in the international transit areas of EU airports, the European Court of Justice found [Thursday](https://curia.europa.eu/jcms/upload/docs/application/pdf/2017-05/cp170047en.pdf)."*

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks. So I assume I can do it right at the transit airport. Or maybe it should (can) be done electronically even before travel?

Comment: Please see [How to declare](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/individuals/cash-controls/how-declare_en). I don't know how or when the declaration form should be submitted, but there is a link at the bottom.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your comments make the basis of a proper answer

Comment: @PeterM my comments were only from google-fu. I have never been through customs when in transit. You are supposed to declare cash that is in baggage too – but you might not even have access to the baggage.

Comment: @WeatherVane A google-fu based answer is still an answer.  And having answer allows for closure, rather than giving the appearance of the question going unanswered.

Comment: This is the form used by most countries: https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/sites/taxation/files/resources/documents/customs/customs_controls/cash_controls/declaration_forms/declaration_form_pt_en.pdf It's unclear though whom to give it to and when, since you are not passing through customs. You can't get to the customs area without going through immigration so you need to find someone airside.

Comment: Someone from the comment section please add an answer so that I can close this question.

Comment: If you got what you needed, and no actual answers have been written yet, you can also *delete* the question.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I think deleting is not the best option. The comments can be helpful for others seeking the same info. I have already found many useful info in the comment section of the questions (with or without accepted answers)

Comment: Well first, see if the question is a duplicate of another already here.  Comments don't have any permanence.   They're only intended to clarify the question, and are often "cleaned up" i.e. mass-deleted. StackExchange is not a discussion forum. Anything good should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane This info you shared does not apply to Turkey, right? I could not find Turkey in the list here: https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/individuals/cash-controls/how-declare_en

Comment: @MuhamadMohaqeq Turkey is not a member of the EU, although its citizens have certain movement rights.

Comment: I have tried to contact Turkish airline as well as Istanbul airport, to try to see how and when I should fill out the declaration form. However, both were non-responsive (and thus unhelpful) at all. Particularly I need to know if I can fill out the form in English or not. Because the link above for EU countries says the form must be filled in the language of the country where you are submitting the form to. I wanted to know if this is true for Turkey or not. I don't know Turkish, so if this needs to be filled out at the airport in Turkish, some prior arrangement must be taken on my side.